# IIS rewrite rule doesn't work

Tags: asp.net, iis, url-rewriting

I want to simply to redirect Radio/Play?stationId=124 to station/124 but below configuration doesn't work. Other rules in my configuration works so rewrite modules working.

```
<rule name="radio-play" stopProcessing="true">
   <match url="^Radio/Play?stationId=([0-9]+)" ignoreCase="true" />
   <action type="Redirect" url="station/{R:1}" redirectType="Permanent" />
</rule>
```

What is wrong in the configuration ?

Comment: Someone can have any idea or clue ?

Answer (score 0):

Handling query string parameter is different. Here is correct way.

```
    <rule name="radio-play" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url="^radio/play" ignoreCase="true" />
      <conditions>
        <add input="{QUERY_STRING}" pattern="stationid=(\d+)"  ignoreCase="true"/>
      </conditions>
      <action type="Redirect" url="istasyon/{C:1}" redirectType="Permanent"  appendQueryString="false"/>
    </rule>
```